# headerLayout for navigationView not showing

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I'm making a simple navigation drawer, however my header.xml is not showing up in my navigation_drawer.xml.

I doubled checked and everything and it seems okay. Did I miss something or do something wrong?

Thankyou!

**activity_navigation_drawer.xml**

[image: image1]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:openDrawer="start"
    android:background="@color/black"
    tools:context=".NavigationDrawer"
    android:id="@+id/drawer">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:background="@color/black"/>

    </RelativeLayout>

    <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/navigationView"
        app:menu="@menu/menu_item"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/header"
        android:background="@color/seekbar_container_color"/>



</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

**header.xml**

[image: image2]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:background="@color/activated_btn_color">


    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:src="@drawable/brightness_icon"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:tint="@color/white"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/btn_txt"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="3dp"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

**styles.xml** snippet:

```
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar"></style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Set the layout_gravity="start|left" to the NavigationView  like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:openDrawer="start"
    android:background="@color/black"
    tools:context=".NavigationDrawer"
    android:id="@+id/drawer">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:background="@color/black"/>

    </RelativeLayout>

    <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/navigationView"
        app:menu="@menu/menu_item"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/header"
        android:layout_gravity="start|left"
        android:background="@color/seekbar_container_color"/>


</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this way, you don't need to add anything else.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout
            android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/container_body"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:orientation="vertical" />

                <include
                    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                    layout="@layout/toolbar"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent" />

            </RelativeLayout>

            <fragment
                android:id="@+id/fragment_navigation_drawer"
                android:name="com.personalclockapp.UI.Drawer.SideDrawerFragment"
                android:layout_width="340dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_gravity="start"
                app:layout="@layout/fragment_navigation_drawer" />

        </androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>



    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

This is fragment_navigation_drawer.xml

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/closeIv"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/_30sdp"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/_30sdp"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/_15sdp"
        android:foregroundTint="@color/white"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_close_white"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/logoIv"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_50sdp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_logo"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/closeIv" />

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/drawerList"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_30sdp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/logoIv"
        android:scrollbars="none"/>

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_sitetrack"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/logoutTv"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fontFamily="@font/roboto_regular"
        android:text="@string/logout"
        android:padding="@dimen/_15sdp"
        android:textSize="@dimen/_12sdp"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/_30sdp"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_logout"
        android:drawablePadding="@dimen/_15sdp"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```